# If I have two rectangles of different sizes(10 by 10 and 20 by 20) in Pygame, how can I figure out when the two rectangles collide?

Tags: python, pygame

I am unable to detect when two rectangles of different sizes collide.

I've tried, "if x == obj_x and y == obj_y:" where x is one rectangle's x-value, obj_x is the other rectangle's x value, and the same for the y-values.

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)

display_width = 500
display_height = 500

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Avoid')

x_change = 0
y_change = 0

FPS = 30
block_size = 10

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",25)


def showLives(lives):
    text = smallfont.render("Lives: "+str(lives), True, white)
    screen.blit(text, [0,0])
def message_to_screen(msg,color):
    screen_text = font.render(msg, True, color)
    screen.blit(screen_text, [100,250])

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def gameLoop():
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False

    x = 250
    y = 425

    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0

    obj_speed = 5


    obj_y = 0
    obj_x = 0

    obj2_y = 0
    obj2_x = 0
    obj2_speed = 3

    lives = 3
    while not gameExit:
        while gameOver == True:
            screen.fill(white)
            message_to_screen("Game Over, Press C to play again or Q to quit", red)
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        gameExit = True
                        gameOver = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameLoop()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -block_size
                    y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = block_size
                    y_change = 0
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    x_change = 0
                    y_change = 0
        if x > 500-block_size:
            x-=block_size
        if x < 0+block_size:
            x+=block_size
 #       if x >= display_width-block_size-block_size or x < 0:
 #           gameOver = True
        obj_y = obj_y + obj_speed
        if obj_y > display_height:
            obj_x = random.randrange(0, display_width-block_size)
            obj_y = -25
        obj2_y = obj2_y + obj2_speed
        if obj2_y > display_height:
            obj2_x = random.randrange(1, display_width-block_size)
            obj2_y = -27

        x += x_change
        y += y_change
        screen.fill(black)

        pygame.draw.rect(screen,white, [obj_x,obj_y,20,20])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,white, [obj2_x,obj2_y,20,20])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, [x,y,block_size,block_size])
        showLives(lives)
        pygame.display.update()
        if x == obj_x and y == obj_y:
            lives -= 1
        if lives == 0:
            gameOver = True
    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

gameLoop()
```

I want the program to detect when any part of the rectangles collide instead of just detecting when one point on each of the rectangles collide.

Comment: `one_rect.colliderect(other_rect)` - see [pygame.Rect.colliderect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect)

Answer (score 1):

PyGame has class [pygame.Rect()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) to keep rectangle's position and size. It uses it to draw images/sprites and check collision between sprites.

```
x = 250
y = 425

obj_y = 0
obj_x = 0

rect_1 = pygame.Rect(x, y, 10, 10)
rect_2 = pygame.Rect(obj_x, obj_y, 20, 20)
```

and then you can check collision

```
rect_1.colliderect(rect_2)
```

You can also use it to draw rectangle on screen

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, rect_2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, rect_1)
```

You can also use it to check collision between rectangle and point - ie. to check if button was clicked by mouse

```
button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos)
```

---

To change values in rectangle you have `rect_1.x`, `rect_1.y`, `rect_1.width`, `rect_1.height` but also

```
x,y
top, left, bottom, right
topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright
midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
center, centerx, centery
size, width, height
w,h
```

Some of them takes tuple with `(x, y)`

for example: center rectangle on screen

```
rect_1.center = (display_width//2, display_height//2)
```

or event using `screen`

```
rect_1.center = screen.get_rect().center
```

OR center text on screen

```
screen_text_rect = screen_text.get_rect()
screen_text_rect.center = screen.get_rect().center

screen.blit(screen_text, screen_text_rect)
```

Comment: This way does work for the collisions, but instead of decreasing the number of lives when the two rectangles collide, it says game over.

Comment: I don't know you current code but when I look at code in question I see that you decrease lives but you don't change positions so in next loop they still collide and it may decrease lives again and again so finally you can see only game over.